# Magnific Popup ajax post get data attribute from element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, magnific-popup

I'm attempting to make an ajax request with Magnific Popup. I need to get the data attribute from the element being clicked (triggering Magnific Popup) and set it as the post data. How do I do this?

Generic, modified example from Magnific Popup's website:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.ajax-popup').magnificPopup({
        type: 'ajax',
        ajax: {
            settings: {
                cache: false,
                data: /* I need data attribute of 
                         this specfic .ajax-popup*/
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Show us some source code sample.